# iPhone uinavigationcontroller issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have 2 views;
View A - shows table lists - Row a, Row b, c...(actually filled from an ext API request)
View B - shows details about the selected row

Now let's say when I click on Row a on view A for the first time, it takes me to a's detail view (ie.e view B). After that I go back to view A. Now when I click on either row a/b, it gives me an error;
Program received signal:  `“EXC_BAD_ACCESS”`.

This issue does not occur every time. In some cases, i can navigate back & forth multiple times.

My code is:

```
bookdetailViewController = [[BookDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good possibility that you can't always repeat it because of timing.  You said that the screens are being populated by an external API request.  Do you set the detail view as the delegate for the API request, so that it is notified when the API request is finished and the data is ready?

I suggest that you can reproduce the error by going very quickly from the list view to the details view but, before the details view can load its data, return to the list view.  If the details view is delegate for the API request, the app will crash because the delegate for the API request has been deallocated before it is able to call whatever delegate message you specified.  If you give the details view time to load the data, you won't experience this crash.

I have a similar bug in an app I'm working on and am avoiding it at the moment with a bit of a hack - in the details view dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
  [super dealloc];
  self = nil;
}
```

If anyone has a smarter way to ensure that a deallocated view is set to `nil`, I welcome their suggestion.

Comment: [receiver release];
receiver = nil;  for ivars
receiver.property = nil; for properties in all the time

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues in the past and it usually ends up being that I released an object without retaining it.  Specifically, you might want to check your views and cells for this.

Comment: I did check that. I am not releasing any obj that is being used. e.g. views/cells
In fact, I am not using retain/release on most of the things.

Comment: It's extremely hard to debug
Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

as it does not give any specific info

Comment: Just to add, I am also passing some info from view A to view B
aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 
 bookdetailViewController.aBook = aBook;
 
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:bookdetailViewController animated:YES];

Comment: One more imp thing I noticed is there is sometimes inconsistency in showing the detail view:
e.g. During 2nd time, if I click on row b, it shows me c's detail...This generally happens only during the 2nd time (i.e. after back/forth)

Comment: You're trying to access memory that's been released. Does the Debugger give you any clues? Look for a method that's with black letters, that's usually your method and where your app crashes. Sounds like it might be `[appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` causing your issue, if you're trying to access an object at an index where no object exists. Also a small side note: Keeping your object model in your App Delegate is not a very good choice. Have a look at some MVC documentation (or WWDC videos if you have a paid developer account)

Comment: In the Console, it does not give any hint. Just says "Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”."
That's the reason I am a bit confused.

Comment: You need to check the Debugger for any clues to where it crashed. The console will only give you so much information. However, if it's only “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” it's not related to accessing the object at index Y in your array, but rather over-releasing an object.

Comment: Also when you say "Keeping your object model in your App Delegate is not a very good choice" could you please let me know in case I need to share an object across multiple classes, how should I go about it ?

Comment: Create a class that handles your model, basically. Again, you should refer to documentation or WWDC videos on MVC (Model, View, Controller). It's a bit hard to grasp at first, but really makes sense when you set everything up this way, and allows for super easy tweaking of your code, or if you ever decide to use the same model/view/controller for an iPad version of your app, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To give you the best answer it would be necessary to see what's in your `viewDidLoad:`, `viewWillAppear:` and probably `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` methods.

With this line:

```
bookdetailViewController = [[BookDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookDetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

you are initialising (and therefore retaining) an instance of BookDetailViewController. Who is handling the release of that when you come back to view A (which I assume is something called BookListViewController or BooksViewController). If no one is responsible for releasing it that's a leak right there, it might not cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS but it's not good.

Comment: Should I release BookDetailViewController inside BookListViewController?

Comment: Ordinarily yes. Usually if you were pushing it onto a navigationcontroller stack you would push and then call release on the detailviewcontroller. What this means essentially is that you are giving up your responsibility for the bookdetailviewcontroller and letting the navigationcontroller determine when to release it.

Comment: Another thought: I don't see you actually declaring bookdetailViewController, I see you setting a value to it. Where did you declare it? Is it an ivar? is it just in the scope of the `didSelectRow:` method? It really probably shouldn't be an ivar.